# Compare two lists with index

Tags: python, list

I have to write a boolean function who takes as argument two lists (`L1` and `L2`) of equal character strings.

`L1` is a list of male given names and `L2` is a list of female given names of the same length.
`L1[k]` gives a gift to `L2 [k]`.

This function should return True if two people exchange gifts with each other, for example:

```
>>> compare(['A','B','C','D','E'],['C','D','A','E','B'])
True
```

```
>>> compare(['A','B','C','D','E'],['B','C','D','E','A'])
False
```

I have to work with the index of lists.

I have written a function to get the index but I have absolutely no idea how to compare these two lists ...

```
def index(name,L):
    i = 0
    for lookup in L:
        if lookup == name: return i
        i += 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: In the "True" example E gives B but B gives D a present. They do not give presents each other.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but your `index` is practically the same as `list.index()`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MichaelButscher it's `if two people exchange gifts` , not all people. I had the same confusion.

Comment: @wjandrea I am not allowed to use this... Unfortunately!

Comment: What determines if someone gives another a gift? *L1[k] gives a gift to L2[k]*? I don't entirely understand.

Comment: @gmdev It is the order of the lists already determined for the starting lists. L1[1] gives to L2[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def compare(A,B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if B[A.index(B[i])]==A[i]:
            return True
        print(B[A.index(B[i])],A[i]) # print to understand more
    return False
```

***Note***

If the two lists don't have similar letters, this won't work, since it refers to the letters.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier (and maybe more efficient) to just make a dict that looks up giver -> recipient. Then you can use it to determine if the giving is symmetrical:

```
def compare(l1, l2):
    d = dict(zip(l1, l2))
    return any(l == d[d[l]] for l in l1)
    
compare(['A','B','C','D','E'],['C','D','A','E','B'])
# True

compare(['A','B','C','D','E'],['B','C','D','E','A'])
# False
```

If you want to test if `all` the giving is symmetrical, you can use `all()` instead of `any()`.

Comment: I like answers like this. They don't do OP's homework for them (since most instructors won't accept answers which go much beyond what they currently know) but instead show the Pythonic ways that such things are done. It might not help them turn in their homework on time, but in the long run it will teach them something useful.

Comment: It is indeed a solution that I've tried but I do not have the right to use dict...

Comment: @JohnColeman I highly discourage more advanced answers for such exercises. if they cant get the hard coded basic ways, they wont get the pythonic way.

Comment: @ombk There is room for things like this and there is room for *hints* for more elementary solutions (hints that don't deprive the student of the learning experience of working out the answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['A','B','C','D','E'] # 1
list2 = ['C','D','A','E','B']`
compared_names = [] # 2

for i in range(len(list1)): # 3
    for j in range(len(list2)): # 4
        if list1[i] == list2[j]: # 5
        compared_names.append(list2[j])
if list1 == compared_names: # 6
    print('True, the lists are equal')
    print('This is the compared_names List: ' + str(compared_names))
else: # 7
    print('False, the lists are not equal')
    print('This is the compared_names list is: ' + str(compared_names))
```

1. The first 2 lists are going to be compared to each other
2. The compared_names list will store the similar items from the lists
3. The for loop is using the variable mn to loop through list1
   you have to take the length of the list so that when index i
   is plugged into the first if statement it is a numeral instead of a string
   ie for i in list1 will return the char 'A', 'B'... so you can't
   compare. Using the range(len()) will provide an index (0, 1,...) of the
   list instead of the char ('A', 'B'...)
4. Everything with the for list1 for loop applies to the list2
   loop. Also, when the list1 loop runs it will enter index zero, and
   then the female_names loop will run it's course (ie 0 through 4). Everytime
   it cycles through an index it will check the if statement.
5. The if statement will plug in the current index of each loop
   so for the first loop around list1[0] == list2[1].
   Since 'A' != 'C' it won't append 'C' to the compared_list, and
   the new loop will go to the next indexes for the next loop around.
6. Once both lists have been cycled through the if statement compares
   both list1 and the compared_names list. If they match then
   True and the compared_list will print out.
7. If list1 and compared_names don't match False and the
   compared_list will print out.

You can take this and turn it into a function like def compare(1, 2): ...
and turn the print into a return.